# MediaRecorder : videos saved on chrome do not show on firefox

Tags: html, webrtc, web-mediarecorder

I do use mediaRecorder:

when I record on FF: FF and chrome: ok

when I record on chrome: chrome is ok and firefox returns: unknown MimeType

When I do examine these recorded videos: I got for chrome:

> ```
> Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline), yuv420p(progressive), 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc
> ```
>
> (default)

and for firefox:

> Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp8, yuv420p(progressive), 640x480, SAR 1:1
>   DAR 4:3, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default

in JS I do use:

```
var options = {mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=vp8'};
```

Any idea on how to record videos on chrome so firefox can read them ?

Comment: You're asking for VP8 and get h264 in Chrome? That sounds odd at least. In what format/ending are you exporting the blob?

Comment: I submit the blog and write a .mp4 file.

Comment: VP8 inside MP4 is probably undefined behaviour. You might want to try if it works if write a webm file.